# Expandable text field merges with another one

Tags: javascript, html

I have a row of text boxes with expandable option. Click in the expandable button...the text fields size doubles and merges with adjacent text field. If the adjacent text fields contains value it will be pushed to the next text field.  Can you suggest me how to do this

Comment: Do you want to solve this using by vanilla javascript? Or it is possible to use jQuery javascript library?

Comment: Either of them is fine

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is not perfect, but it helps you to get started. You could try this by running the snippet.

```js
$("[data-merge-to]").click(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.data("merge-to") === "right") {
    var $left = $this.closest(".input-group").find("input").first();
    var $right = $this.closest("[class^=col-]").next().find("input").first();
  }
  if ($this.data("merge-to") === "left") {
    var $left = $this.closest("[class^=col-]").prev().find("input").first();
    var $right = $this.closest(".input-group").find("input").first();
  }
  var merged = $.grep([$left.val(), $right.val()], function(str) {
    return typeof str === "string" && str.length > 0;
  }).join(" ");
  var lContainer = $left.closest("[class^=col-]");
  var rContainer = $right.closest("[class^=col-]");
  var leftW = parseInt(lContainer.attr("class").match(/(?!col-\w{2}-)\d+\b/i));
  var rightW = parseInt(rContainer.closest("[class^=col-]").attr("class").match(/(?!col-\w{2}-)\d+\b/i));
  $left.val(merged);
  lContainer.removeClass().addClass("col-xs-" + (leftW + rightW));
  rContainer.remove();
  if(lContainer.is(":last-child")) {
    lContainer.find(".input-group-btn:last-child").remove();
    if(!lContainer.has(".input-group-btn").length) {
      $left.prependTo(lContainer).nextAll().remove();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="value 1">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-merge-to="right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-horizontal" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-merge-to="left"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-horizontal" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="value 2">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-merge-to="right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-horizontal" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-merge-to="left"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-horizontal" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="value 3">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Bootstrap framework and jQuery are used here, but you could modify this.